# Web forms GridView not displaying properly in browsers other than IE

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms, cross-browser

I am trying to update a rickety old ASP.NET Web Forms app to work on modern browsers (our shop has only supported it in IE for years).

Among other issues I'm having, I cannot get GridViews to display properly in several parts of the app. In particular, the width of the column headers is being set incorrectly, distorting the whole grid.

In IE, a grid looks like this:

[image: gridview IE]

Whereas in Chrome, Firefox, etc., I get this:

[image: gridview Chrome]

Note the distorted Account # header size, and how the data entry cells do not align with the rest of the column headers (Account Title, FY's...)

I believed this to be a simple CSS issue of some kind, but none of the changes I made had any effect whatsoever in the modern browsers - they simply would not respond, even when I tried to edit styling in-line in the DOM explorer.

Weirdly, the column headers are given ItemStyle-Width and ItemStyle-CssClass attributes in the .aspx, but those don't seem to be reflected in the generated HTML markup at all, as far as I can tell.

I do see that those cells are give "colSpan='1'" and "rowSpan='1'" attributes in the markup in IE and not in the modern browsers, so it seems IE is interpreting what .NET is sending it differently (to state the obvious, I guess). I don't know exactly what those attributes mean, though, as I have never seen them written with camel casing like that. I also can't find/don't understand where those attributes come from in the code... perhaps it's just something baked in to the way the control is rendered, again.

Here is the .aspx for the whole gridview pictured. Please let me know if anything else would be helpful.

```
     <div id="dvByFund" style= "width: 100%;">
     <asp:GridView 
        runat="server" 
        id="grdCashReceiptsByFund" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        Width="100%"
        RowStyle-CssClass="GridListItem"
        AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="GridListItemAlt"
        HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridListItemAlt"
        OnRowDataBound="grdCashReceiptsByFund_RowDataBound"
        ShowFooter="True"
        CellPadding="2"
        >

        <Columns>

            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="invisible" HeaderStyle-CssClass="invisible" FooterStyle-CssClass="invisible">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:label runat="server" id="lblGovernmentalLevel" />
                    <asp:label runat="server" id="lblGovernmentalLevelDescription" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Account #" ItemStyle-Width="50px" ItemStyle-CssClass="AmountCell">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtFundNumber" Width="35px" CssClass="Normal" onblur="verifyFundExists(this);" MaxLength="3" onchange="formChanged=true;" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Account Title" ItemStyle-Width="230px" ItemStyle-CssClass="AmountCell">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" id="lblFundDescription" Width="210px" CssClass="ReadonlyLabelNoBorder" />
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtFundDescription" CssClass="invisible" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Major<br /> Source" ItemStyle-Width="50px" ItemStyle-CssClass="AmountCell">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtMajorSource" Width="35px" CssClass="Normal" MaxLength="2" onchange="formChanged=true;" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Source" ItemStyle-Width="50px" ItemStyle-CssClass="AmountCell">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtSource" Width="35px" CssClass="Normal" MaxLength="2" onchange="formChanged=true;" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type" ItemStyle-Width="100px" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-CssClass="AmountCell">
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:DropDownList id="ddlAppropriationType" CssClass="Normal" runat="server" DataValueField="key" DataTextField="value" onchange="formChanged=true;" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    Totals:
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>            

            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-Width="90px" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" FooterStyle-Font-Bold="true" ItemStyle-CssClass="AmountCell">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtFirstSessionYear" total="dvFundFirstSessionYearTotal" onchange="amountChanged(this);" onkeypress="FormatForAmount(11, '0', this);" onfocus="subtractFromTotal(this);amountFocused(this);" Width="90px" CssClass="NormalAmountNoBorder" onblur="amountBlurred(this);"  />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <div id="dvFundFirstSessionYearTotal" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-Width="90px" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" FooterStyle-Font-Bold="true" ItemStyle-CssClass="AmountCell">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtSecondSessionYear" total="dvFundSecondSessionYear" onchange="amountChanged(this);" onkeypress="FormatForAmount(11, '0', this);" onfocus="subtractFromTotal(this);amountFocused(this);" Width="90px" CssClass="NormalAmountNoBorder" onblur="amountBlurred(this);" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <div id="dvFundSecondSessionYear" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-Width="90px" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" FooterStyle-Font-Bold="true" ItemStyle-CssClass="AmountCell">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtThirdSessionYear" total="dvFundThirdSessionYear" onchange="amountChanged(this);" onkeypress="FormatForAmount(11, '0', this);" onfocus="subtractFromTotal(this);amountFocused(this);" Width="90px" CssClass="NormalAmountNoBorder" onblur="amountBlurred(this);" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <div id="dvFundThirdSessionYear" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-Width="90px" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" FooterStyle-Font-Bold="true" ItemStyle-CssClass="AmountCell">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtFourthSessionYear" total="dvFundFourthSessionYear" onchange="amountChanged(this);" onkeypress="FormatForAmount(11, '0', this);" onfocus="subtractFromTotal(this);amountFocused(this);" Width="90px" CssClass="NormalAmountNoBorder" onblur="amountBlurred(this);" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <div id="dvFundFourthSessionYear" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-Width="90px" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" FooterStyle-Font-Bold="true" ItemStyle-CssClass="AmountCell">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtFifthSessionYear" total="dvFundFifthSessionYear" onchange="amountChanged(this);" onkeypress="FormatForAmount(11, '0', this);" onfocus="subtractFromTotal(this);amountFocused(this);" Width="90px" CssClass="NormalAmountNoBorder" onblur="amountBlurred(this);" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <div id="dvFundFifthSessionYear" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-Width="90px" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" FooterStyle-Font-Bold="true" ItemStyle-CssClass="AmountCell">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtSixthSessionYear" total="dvFundSixthSessionYear" onchange="amountChanged(this);" onkeypress="FormatForAmount(11, '0', this);" onfocus="subtractFromTotal(this);amountFocused(this);" Width="90px" CssClass="NormalAmountNoBorder" onblur="amountBlurred(this);" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <div id="dvFundSixthSessionYear" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
     </asp:GridView>

     <asp:Button id="btnAddByFundRow" runat="server" Text="Add Row" OnClientClick="addByFundRow(); return false;" class="CommandButton" />
     </div>
```

CSS applied to AmountCell class:

```
.AmountCell
    {
        border: solid 1px silver;
    }
```

And here's a weird error I get when I remove the ItemStyle-Width and ItemSytle-CssClass attributes from all the TemplateFields:

[image: error]

Basically, expected results: this gridview looks the same across browsers (appearing the way it does in IE, with columns correctly aligned with their headers).

Actual results: IE looks fine, Chrome/Firefox looks distorted.

I'm not the foremost expert on how Web Forms work (by a long-shot), so any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

UPDATE: After playing around with Dev Tools for a while, I was able to learn that the generated .html markup includes an inline style for each row element of the GridView:

```
style="display:block;"
```

Eliminating this inline style from a tr element pops the row's columns back into proper alignment.

The trouble is, I still don't know how to get rid of that in the code... it doesn't appear to be something explicitly added, but rather just baked into the asp.net control.

Again, any and all insight much appreciated!

Comment: What CSS is being applied for class 'AmountCell'

Comment: Also, get rid of that ````<br />```` inside the HeaderText

Comment: What I'd start doing: remove all classes and width settings from the TemplateFields and keep the GridView Width as 100%.  The table should auto-fit itself, so I'm thinking your CSS is manipulating it afterwards.

Comment: Nothing too fancy in that class, just some basic border styling.  Added it above.

I agree that <br /> is silly and should go (to reiterate - not my code! haha). Unfortunately, it doesn't affect the issue I'm having.

EDIT: will try removing all classes and width settings... I feel like I've done this and it really screwed things up, but I'll try again to make sure I'm doing exactly this and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Does this grid use frozen/sticky headers? Have you tried removing all the hard-coded widths? i.e `ItemStyle-Width="50px"` and see what happens

Comment: Just about to try - stay tuned, and thanks!

Comment: Possibly save some headache by testing within browser using browser's dev tools. Remove classes there to see results right away.

Comment: Got waylaid by some meetings and such, but I tried removing all the ItemStyle (Width and CssClass) attributes from the .aspx, and I just got an even stranger result - a parser error (screenshot added to question).  I have no idea why it's throwing such an error on that particular line, since the ItemTemplate directly above the one it stops at is identical in basically every way except the id.  The mystery deepens...

Comment: Also, I have tried working in the developer tools, but the html markup that's produced doesn't give me a lot to work with.  For example, the most screwed up of all the cells (the "Account #" header) has no css classes for me to even try removing. It just looks like "<th scope="col">Account #</th>".

Comment: @JohnPete22 UPDATE: I was able to determine in developer tools that removing some inline styling that set style="display: block;" on <tr> elements wrapping each row fixes the problem.  However, I cannot find where in the code that is added/generated...

Comment: Well <tr>'s dont normally have that style, so something else is adding it.  Like I said, I would remove *all* CSS -- every RowStyle in the GridView or ItemStyle on the items or HeaderStyle. All styles. The table, at it's base style, will auto-fit it's area.  Then start adding styles in until you find your culprit.